# Kohana ORM does not return primary key of newly added record

Tags: postgresql, orm, kohana, sequence

Interesting problem case in Kohana ORM using PostgreSQL.

Here is the situation

```
$oM = ORM::factory('SomeModel');//Postgre SQL
//Column id is a primary key with some serial type
$oM->column = 'some value';
$oM->save();

var_dump($oM->id);//or $oM->pk();
//prints bool(true)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was hidden in the sequence privileges. As a fan of the minimalistic privileges set up, I have given only "update" privilege for the user for the id sequence of the table.

As the insert query does not use "Returning" statement, it seems that the ORM reads the sequence value after that. When this right is not set up, it just returns "true" instead of some warning or error.